# My image isn't being deployed by kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have made a minimal image of a fast-api program by building its Dockerfile. The imagename is `task1`. I'm trying to deploy it locally with minikube, kubectl by specifying a file named `task1-deployment.yaml` with the following structure:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: task1-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: task1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: task1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: task1
          image: task1:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

Whenever I run `kubectl -f apply task1-deployment.yaml` it shows a successful message, yet when running `kubectl get deployment`, task1 isn't ready and can't be accessed at localhost:8080. 
The other official-pulled images work, what am I doing wrong?

Note: "imagePullPolicy" doesn't change anything

Comment: When you create a container only in docker with your image does that work?

Comment: Minikube can't get images from your machine's docker - you need to load it into the minikube cluster with `minikube image load <image_name>`

Comment: @Manish yes it does

Comment: @LeonardoDagnino Thank you it worked! That was the part that my tutorial skipped!

Comment: Did you get any error information from `kubectl describe deployment task1-deployment`?

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as an answer instead of a comment:

Minikube can't get images from your machine's docker - you need to load it into the minikube cluster by running  the following command:

```
$ minikube image load <image_name>
```